# Send a return through a mongoose model

Tags: javascript, mongoose

So I have this model :

'use strict';

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var subscriberModel = function () {
  var subscriberSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: String
  });

function validateEmail(email) { 
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

subscriberSchema.methods.validateSubscriber = function (subs, otherModel) {
  var code = 0;
  if (validateEmail(subs.email)) {
    mongoose.model('Subscriber').findOne({'email': subs.email},
    function(err, subscriber){
      if (err) {
        code = 2;
      } else if (subscriber) {
        code = 3;
      } else {
        subs.save(function(err){
          if (err) {
            code = 2;
          }
          code = 4;
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      code = 1;
    }
  };

  return mongoose.model('Subscriber', subscriberSchema);
};

module.exports = new subscriberModel();
```

And I call it in another file that way :

```
    var subscriberModel = require('../models/subscriber');
    var subscriber = new subscriberModel({email: req.body.email.trim()});
    var code = subscriber.validateSubscriber(subscriber, buyModel);
    console.log('code = %s', code); // => displays "code = 0"
```

I guess it's a scope problem or something like that (because I don't use any callback -or maybe I should-) but I can't find nor the problem, nor the solution.
So, how can I get the returned code value ?
Thanks in advance.

[EDIT] :  I found where the problem was and edited the code to explain it. So apparently my var is set in the callbacks of mongoose so now my question is; how do I wait for this callback to end as I need the result to display a message to the user in a webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so, I found the answer.
I edited my function  `validateSubscriber` to send a callback: `subscriberSchema.methods.validateSubscriber = function (subs, callback)`. And removed the otherModel occurences inside.

That way, when I call it in my other file I just have to do :

```
subscriber.validateSubscriber(subscriber, function(code){
    buyModel.code = code;
    console.log('code = %s', buyModel.code);
}
```

To get the code AND wait for the answer.

I hope it helped someone else.